# Is there any existing GWT integration with sharethis or addthis?

Tags: gwt

I am looking for a way to use the addthis or sharethis service in GWT. 
These services allow to publish a page to social networks or by email.
Couldn't find anything on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes try this AddThis GWT Widget out: http://code.google.com/p/gwt-addthis/